# How to Populate Where condition To Execute Later in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Consider this code

```
$amUser = User::where('status',1)->get();
$data=[];
foreach($amUser as $a){
    $salescalls = $a->salesCall();
    if (isset($request->corporate_name))
    {
        $salescalls=$salescalls->where('corporate_name','like','%'.$request->corporate_name.'%');
    }
    if (isset($request->start_date))
    {
        $salescalls=$salescalls->whereDate('sales_calls.created_at','>=',$request->start_date);
    }
    if (isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $salescalls=$salescalls->whereDate('sales_calls.created_at','<=',$request->end_date);
    }
    $data[$a->id]=$salescalls->get();
    $grandTotal['sum']+=$salescalls->count();
}
```

As you see it will execute salesCall() query on each loop and producing n+1 problem, but if I eager loading `$amUser->load('salesCall')` I can't do `whereDate`query so my strategy is build all where condition and then populate all user id then combining them all together in one execution, but I don't know how to populate all these where condition and call them later. How to do that or any advice?

Comment: Missing `->get()` => `$amUser = User::where('status',1)->get()`

Comment: thank you mas, this is simplified version of my controller hehe so I need to keep it understandable by the others

Comment: is there a reason you aren't doing this from the other direction? Do this from `SalesCall` side and use `whereHas` to constrain it to only the users with a 'status' of 1

Comment: @lagbox in user i also have regional relation, the final result is a report of how many salescall each user for each regional, for xample regional ABC has 2 users, so total salescall of ABC should be sum of those user's salescall

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto I have no issue with your code. Are there any errors? We recommend that you provide details about the request.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto yes no issue and no error, it just executing every quey of $a->salesCall() each loop, i need to avoid that

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto oh i see. I will try to answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building a query, you may specify which relationships should be eager loaded using the `with` method :

```
$amUser = User::with('salescalls')
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->get();
```

Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship but also specify additional query conditions for the eager loading query. You can accomplish this by passing an array of relationships to the `with` method where the array key is a relationship name and the array value is a closure that adds additional constraints to the eager loading query :

```
$amUser = User::with(['salescalls' => function($query) use ($request){
    if($request->corporate_name){
        $query->where('corporate_name', 'like', '%' . $request->corporate_name . '%');
    }

    if($request->start_date){
        $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $request->start_date);
    }

    if($request->end_date){
        $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->end_date);
    }
}])->where('status', 1)->get();
```

So you don't need to use `foreach`. Eager loading alleviates the "N + 1" query problem.

And oh, you can also use [`when` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#conditional-clauses) btw.

---

**But I want to only retrieve salescalls data**

Yes you can :

```
$data = $amUser->pluck('salescalls');
```

**Then, how to count data? (without empty collection)**

```
$grandTotal = $amUser->pluck('salescalls')->flatten()->count();
```